# Delphi Inconsistent data coming from a hardware using Cport

Tags: delphi, tcomport

I am having trouble getting the serial port data from an equipment.
Below is the image of the expected result:

Desire result:

[image]

Unwanted result:

[image]

I use Ttimer so I can automatically get the data and put it to the Memo.

I need the data to be placed line by line in the memo.

This is the source code:

```
procedure TForm3.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
k: Integer;
InBuffer: array[1..500] of char;

begin

for k:=1 to 500  do
InBuffer[k]:=' '; 
Trim(InBuffer);

if cport.Connected = true then
begin
ComLed1.Kind := lkGreenLight;
cport.ReadStr(str,k);
Trim(str);
S:=str;

if str = '' then
begin

end
else
begin
memo1.lines.Add(str);
end;
end
else
begin
ComLed1.Kind := lkredLight; 
txt_com_status1.Caption := 'Connected';
end;
end;
```

My question is what is the problem? And what is the solution for this.

Comment: It would be easier to read your code if you used some indentation.

Comment: Remove CR(#13) and LF(#10) from your string. There is also a timing problem, since you must know when the equipment has finished sending the string.

Comment: side note: if the packets from the hw have SOP and EOP(it should), you might want to buffer the data to avoid processing fragmented packets and use S/EOP to extract, then format as you please

Answer (score 3):

`TMemo.Lines.Add()` adds a **line**. The text you add will have a line break inserted at the end of it.  It is clear that you are receiving the hardware data in pieces, and you are adding each piece separately as its own line in the Memo.

To do what you are attempting, you need to either:

1. Read the pieces from the hardware and cache them until you detect the end of a complete message, and then `Add()` only complete messages to the Memo.  How you do this depends on the particular protocol the hardware is using to send data to you.  Does it wrap the data in `STX`/`ETX` markers? Does it delimit messages? We don't know, you have not provided any information about that. And your code is trying (unsuccessfully) to trim a lot of data away that it probably shouldn't be throwing away at all.
2. Don't use `Add()` at all.  You can use the `SelText` property instead to avoid inserting any line breaks you don't want.

   ```
   memo1.SelStart := memo1.GetTextLen;
   memo1.SelLength := 0;
   memo1.SelText := str;
   ```

That being said, your timer code is doing some odd things. `InBuffer` is filled with spaces, then (unsuccessfully) trimmed, and then completely ignored.  You are passing an uninitialized `k` value to `ReadStr()`. The `str` value you do read is unsuccessfully trimmed before added to the Memo. You are assigning `str` to `S` and then ignoring `S`.

Try this instead:

```
procedure TForm3.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  str: AnsiString;
begin
  if cport.Connected then
  begin
    ComLed1.Kind := lkGreenLight;
    txt_com_status1.Caption := 'Connected';
    cport.ReadStr(str, 256);
    str := Trim(str);    
    if str <> '' then
    begin
      memo1.SelStart := memo1.GetTextLen;
      memo1.SelLength := 0;
      memo1.SelText := str;
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    ComLed1.Kind := lkredLight; 
    txt_com_status1.Caption := 'Disconnected';
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively (assuming you are using `TComPort` that has an `OnRxChar` event):

```
procedure TForm3.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if cport.Connected then
  begin
    ComLed1.Kind := lkGreenLight;
    txt_com_status1.Caption := 'Connected';
  end
  else
  begin
    ComLed1.Kind := lkredLight; 
    txt_com_status1.Caption := 'Disconnected';
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.cportRxChar(Sender: TObject; Count: Integer);
var
  str: AnsiString;
begin
  cport.ReadStr(str, Count);
  str := Trim(str);    
  if str <> '' then
  begin
    memo1.SelStart := memo1.GetTextLen;
    memo1.SelLength := 0;
    memo1.SelText := str;
  end;
end;
```

---

**Edit** based on new information provided in comments, try something like this:

```
private
  buffer: AnsiString;
  portConnected: boolean;

procedure TForm3.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if cport.Connected then
  begin
    if not portConnected then
    begin
      portConnected := true;
      buffer := '';
      ComLed1.Kind := lkGreenLight;
      txt_com_status1.Caption := 'Connected';
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    if portConnected then
    begin
      portConnected := false;
      ComLed1.Kind := lkredLight; 
      txt_com_status1.Caption := 'Disconnected';
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.cportRxChar(Sender: TObject; Count: Integer);
var
  str: AnsiString;
  i: integer;
begin
  cport.ReadStr(str, Count);
  buffer := buffer + str;
  repeat
    i := Pos(#10, buffer);
    if i = 0 then Exit;
    str := Copy(buffer, 1, i-1);
    Delete(buffer, 1, i);
    memo1.Lines.Add(str);
  until buffer = '';
end;
```

Comment: sir Remy the hardware doesnt have stx/etx on it, also it doesnt delimits any char.. I need to get all the data from the hardware, and get only the useful data.

Comment: does it possible if I put a prefix and suffix to the hardware data and read only the data between them? do I need to use timer because the hardware is program to send automatically? how to do it sir? Thanks in advance again. :)

Comment: @YeojsonBarcelo like most protocols, there needs to be a defined beginning and ending to each message that is sent, whether it is a hardware signal or a software delimiter. How exactly does the hardware indicate on the serial port where one message ends and the next begins? There has to be something. What kind of device are you communicating with? What does its documentation say about the serial protocol being used?

Comment: You are asking too many questions and not providing useful info about the system you are communicating with. We are not here to make guesses. Please be more specific.

Comment: Batchno= 1, Date=08/03/16, Timestart=10:34 pm, Timeend=10:34 pm, Lotno=12346, Ingredient=H3, Weight=300.2kg [nextLine]

this is the code I am sorry Sir Remy I am just a Beginner.

Comment: @YeojsonBarcelo is the device *actually sending* a new line character/sequence over the serial port as part of the data? Or are you just *wanting* to display a new line after the data? It makes a big difference. Is the format of the serial data fixed length? Or at least fixed fields of a fixed order? You might be able to use the `kg` as the message delimiter if there is no other option.

Comment: Yes the new line character is from the serial port, yes the length is fixed also the order is fixed. How to do it sir?

Comment: @YeojsonBarcelo well, there you go then. Simply read from the port and append whatever is read to a string variable, and whenever you encounter a new line character then extract that message from the variable and add it to the Memo.

Comment: @YeojsonBarcelo: Stop adding details and new questions to the comments. if you have details to add, [edit] your question and add them there where they belong. If you have other questions, then create new questions to ask them instead of using the comments.

Comment: Sir @remy  the code you provide did not work it doesnt read the data from the port.. Btw I use rs485 for the connection.. Error on str : ansistring

Comment: @YeojsonBarcelo you have not yet specified exactly which serial component you are actually using, so I'm making educated guesses based on what I see in your original code, and what I know is commonly used. Please stop making me guess. What **exact** version of Delphi are you using? What **exact** Delphi component are you using? What **exact** errors are you seeing with the code I have given you so far?